# How to autogenerate properties in a metaclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming, metaclass

How to generate properties in python using metaclass?
I have some data records which fields have some relations between them.
and I would like to have each record as a type(class) and auto generate those properties and relations.

I want to specify this relation as a data structure (say dict) and auto generate classes with properties

```
Record 1
        Field        description
       ----------------------------
        numOfPin      no# of following pin array
        pin_array     array with numOfpin elements
        read_result   if opt_flag bit 0 is set, invalid. ignore this value
        opt_flag       ...
Record 2
   ....
```

Edit: to clarify..
The logic for properties for missing/invalid field and optional flag is the same for all records. So I'd like to abstract this in meta-class.

e.g in pseudo python code:

```
record1_spec = { 'numOfpin', ('pin_array','numOfPin'),
                 'opt_flag', ('read_result','opt_flag') }
record2_spec = { 'numOfsite', ('site_array','numOfsite'),
                 'opt_flag', ('test_result','opt_flag') }

class MetaClass:
    getter_generator( ele, opt ):
       if opt : return ele
       else return None

    get class name (eg. record1) then fetch record_spec to create class
    for ele in record_spec:
       if ele is tuple type:   # relation between field
           class.attribute[ele[0]] = getter_generator(ele[0], ele[1])


class record1(metaclass = Metaclass):
    ...
```

Then `record1` class will have all properties defined in `record1_spec`.
The logic is if some option field is set, some properties return appropriate value.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do and whether you need metaclassing at all for your needs. How do you intend to assign the field values for example? Note that a metaclass defines how the class itself is created and not how the instances of the class is defined.

Comment: @skyking I want to metaclass to create classes (for each record type. not record object!) and each record *type* will need to have some properties and this properties can also be generated by metaclass. I've the basic idea. but all online python metaclass guide/tutorials are not very helpful.

Comment: Could you supply an example on how you would like to use this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a description showing the class that would be generated by the `class record1(metaclass = Metaclass):` statement. It's unclear to me exactly what properties you want automatically generated and added to it (as swell as exactly what actions are they are perform).

Answer (score 5):

OK, let's see how deep the rabbit hole goes...

There are two things you seem to need to do. One is to create properties on the fly, the other is to have them added. First let's look into the creation of properties, which is quite straight forward - a property is created by putting `@property` before the function definition, or as decorators happens to behave - to call `property` with the function as argument. So we create a function on the fly, and call `property` on that, easy:

```
def make_property(params):
    def fn(self):
         return use_self_and_params_to_calculate_result(self, params)
    return property(fn)
```

for example `params` could for example be a field name, and then you can return it by just do `return getattr(self, fieldname)` in the inner (ie `fn`) function.

Now for the next part, creating class. The `metaclass` parameter in class creation is used directly only for that - it doesn't have to be the actual metaclass, it's just called and is supposed to return something which is taken to be the class. Normal usecase though is to have the `metaclass` parameter being the type of the class, but we don't actually need that in this case:

```
def meta(name, bases, attrs):
    attrs = dict(attrs)

    attrs["x"] = make_property("_x")

    return type(name, bases, attrs)

class record1(metaclass=meta):
    pass
```

Now we **could** lookup `record1_spec` in `meta` via `globals()` (`meta` is called with `"record1"` as the first argument), but what's the fun in that. Let's dig deeper into the rabit hole, the `meta` is just called with whatever you put where baseclasses goes - it just happens to be that `type` expect them to be classes, but we need not do that, we only have to make sure that's true when we call `type`:

```
def meta(name, bases, attrs):
    record_spec = bases[0]
    bases = bases[1:]

    attrs = dict(attrs)

    examine_record_spec_and_populate_attrs(attrs, record_spec)
    attrs["spec"] = record_spec

    return type(name, bases, attrs)

class record1(['numOfpin', ('pin_array','numOfPin'), 
              'opt_flag', ('read_result','opt_flag')], metaclass=meta):
    pass
```

Then you can find the spec as `record1.spec` if you should need that. If your record spec is in key-value pairs (ie like a `dict`) you could even use keyword parameters in the class definition:

```
 def meta(name, bases, attrs, **spec):
    attrs = dict(attrs)

    examine_record_spec_and_populate_attrs(attrs, spec)
    attrs["spec"] = spec

    return type(name, bases, attrs)

class record1(numOfpin = ('pin_array','numOfPin'), 
              opt_flag = ('read_result','opt_flag'), metaclass=meta):
    pass
```